# Is `return 5;` a statement or expression in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am not a nitpicker, but from [Statements and expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html#statements-and-expressions):

> We’ve actually already used statements and expressions. Statements are instructions that perform some action and do not return a value. Expressions evaluate to a resulting value. Let’s look at some examples.
>
> ......
>
> Expressions do not include ending semicolons. If you add a semicolon to the end of an expression, you turn it into a statement, which will then not return a value. Keep this in mind as you explore function return values and expressions next.

So for `return 5;`, is it a statement or expression? If it is a statement, a statement should not return value; if it is an expression, an expression should not have an ending semicolon.

Comment: I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/1542) about this wording.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The wording there is inexact. When it says "a statement...will not return a value", it means that a statement is not processed by evaluating it into a final value (as an expression is), but is rather processed by executing it. In the case of a `return` statement, the execution takes the form of exiting the current function, passing the return value to the calling function.

`return 5;` is most certainly a statement.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `return` is *absolutely* an expression.  It's just that `return 5;` is an expression statement, where the expression is a `return` expression.  And just to forestall the potential follow-up: the value of a `return` expression is `!`.

Comment: @DK Just to nit-pick, `!` is the _type_ of the `return` expression, not its value.  The definining property of the `!` type is that it doesn't have any values.

Comment: I just noticed that this makes the wording in the documentation even more confusing, since expressions of type `!` don't evaluate to any value, while the documentation defines expressions as something that _does_ evaluate to a value.

Comment: expression, statement and _expression statement_? This is confusing!

Comment: @jcollum Keep at it, you'll get it.

Comment: @Sneftel could you add an aside to your answer clarifying why `macro_rules!` considers `return 5` an `expr` and not a `stmt` per answer below?

Comment: @ecoe Because `return 5` alone is an expression. Note the lack of the semicolon.

Comment: (Note that it is *also* (potentially)  a statement, in the same way that `5` is both an integer literal and an expression.)

Answer (score 2):

You can find out via Rust macros:

```
macro_rules! expr_or_stmt {
    ($_:expr) => {
        "expr"
    };
    ($_:stmt) => {
        "stmt"
    };
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(expr_or_stmt!(return 5));
}
```

It prints "expr", as you can see on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa1bcf48a1184ce56ca188b03441e97c).

Comment: Interesting... `return 5` matches both `expr` and `stmt` ([change the order to see](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b59df81b096f0a3a648e8d28501e1a75))

Comment: @kmdreko funny... Is it a bug? Are there any more examples of such behavior?

Comment: what is the meanning of "$_:expr" and "$_:stmt"? Can you please provide a link to them?

Comment: @HoangTrinh `$` shows the beginning of a macro "parameter", `_` is its name, `:` separates its name and "type". `expr` means "expression", `stmt` - "statement", see https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html.